# DynamoDB strongly consistent read with query PK with SK range

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's say we have a DynamoDB table with that has a partition key as a string and sort key as a string.

**Question 1.** If a `Query` operation is run where the partition key is provided and but the sort key is not, will DynamoDB return all of the items that match the partition key in a strongly consistent manner?

**Question 2.** If a `Query` operation is run where the partition key is provided, the sort key is not but there is `BETWEEN` expression applied to the sort key, will DynamoDB return all of the items that match the partition key and the sort key expression in a strongly consistent manner?

I can't find anything that calls this out explicitly in the documentation but I remember reading about something years back that stated both the partition key and the sort key must be provided to provide strongly consistent reads.

The [current documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) makes me think this will be strongly consistent, but I was curious if I was missing something obvious.

> Read operations such as GetItem, Query, and Scan provide an optional ConsistentRead parameter. If you set ConsistentRead to true, DynamoDB returns a response with the most up-to-date data, reflecting the updates from all prior write operations that were successful. Strongly consistent reads are only supported on tables and local secondary indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly consistent means you're wanting to read from the leader node of the partition, which always has the very latest data. If you ask for a strongly consistent read, that's what you get. An eventually consistent read might read from a follower node.

(I have a feeling you may be asking about transactional consistency, which is different.)

Comment: Thanks! More specifically, I'm curious about read after write consistency when using a partition key without a sort a sort key when using a Query command - on a table that has both a sort key and a partition key.

Comment: You’re still reading from the leader node so you’re reading from the node that always has the latest data.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a source is is that just generally assumed?

Comment: https://youtu.be/0iGR8GnIItQ